# Upgraded Monero GUI, but getting an issue with "update needed"

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, update

I just "updated" from v0.12.2.0 because I was getting the message "update needed".  I downloaded [Current Version: 0.12.3.0 Lithium Luna](https://getmonero.org/downloads/), extracted the .zip to a new directory, but I still have the same status.

> > > status
> > >       [9/19/2018 10:25 AM] Height: 1664779/1664779 (100.0%) on mainnet, mining at 47 H/s, net hash 571.72 MH/s, v7, **update needed**, 8(out)+0(in) connections, uptime 0d 0h 35m 46s
> > >       refresh
> > >       [9/19/2018 10:26 AM] Monero 'Lithium Luna' (v0.12.3.0-release)

Did I do something wrong? When the Wallet splashscreen popped up, I followed some prompts, then I entered in my keys.  Maybe I should have done something differently?

Comment: Where did you enter your keys by the way? Because normally a new version of the wallet should load your wallet automatically. There recently was a bug though, so maybe you were affected by that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The daemon displays this warning approximately a month in advance of a scheduled protocol upgrade. However, sometimes the new version is not ready yet and you simply need to wait until v0.13.0.0 is released to update. Note that a scheduled protocol upgrade is planned for ~18 October. Thus, make sure to upgrade before that date.

> Did I do something wrong?

No.